# Unable to convert unicode byte to ASCII

Tags: python, unicode

I've gone through about 20 threads but don't seem to be able to find an answer to what I hoped was a simple question!

I have a unicode-encoded byte `"\xbf"` which translates to a `"¿"` character.

If I encode the character as follows:  `u"¿".encode("cp1252")` it outputs `"\xbf"`.  How can I return this back to a `"¿"` character for display on screen?

No matter what I attempt, I seem to get an `ordinal not in range(128)` error.

**EDIT:** A further example of this is simply using `chr(191)`, which also gives the result `"\xbf"`.  How can I make this print the ASCII character?

Any and all help appreciated!

Comment: (That’s a CP1252-encoded byte, not any form of Unicode.) What happens if you `print(u"¿")`?

Comment: use `decode` ,`char = u"¿".encode("cp1252")` ,now you get character back using decode `char.decode("cp1252")`

Comment: *How can I return this back to a "¿" character for display on screen?* Simply with setting the display's encoding to "cp1252".

Comment: So if I use `char.decode("cp1252")`, the result is `u'\xbf'`.  If I `print(u"¿")`, the result is `¿`.  I've tested on both Windows and Linux with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

So after much experimentation and for reasons I don't fully understand, the following code works:

`print "%s" %("\xbf").decode("cp1252")`

It's a workable solution so I'll call this one solved!